# Using ( ) in printf argument list. What does this syntax mean?

Tags: c

I run into a code:

`printf("\tout:\t%-14.14s\n", (sprintf(tmpbuf[0], "[%s]", mystring), tmpbuf[0]));`

What does those sentence in () with sprintf mean?

Comment: Please don't do this in production code.

Comment: I can understand that you dislike this code, but how is it less suitable specifically for production?

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: It surprises people.

Comment: So, the difference between production and, say, development environment is that in production people aren't to be surprised? I mean, in production people normally don't even see the code ;)

Comment: @AlexandreC., I actually disagree with that too (and I don't know why would you care as long as it's not *your* playground), but yes as long as you don't see production as something special WRT such code I can at least understand you :)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin, presumably developers are writing for production so AlexandreC's comment applies there, too.  If you're writing a quick one-off hack to get something done, then it doesn't matter.  If the code will have to be maintained...  Write code that is easy to read.

Comment: I see, we have a different idea of "production". BTW, this code is easy to read. One can, of course, avoid subordinate clauses in human languages as well to make sure everyone understands.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: This is where we disagree: for someone who has a fuzzy knowledge of C (many programmers, especially young ones have), anything involving the comma operator can trigger a misunderstanding of what the code does. This may be easy to read for us, but not for everyone. (btw by production code, I mean any situation involving someone else reading your code).

Comment: @AlexandreC., yes, that's what I meant by different idea of "production". This is perfect truth what you say, it's just that when I talk to my daughter I do not use simple sentences, but rather expect her to develop and understand more and more complex ones. And she's not disappointing me ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is an expression involving the comma operator, to put the following into a single line:

```
sprintf(tmpbuf[0], "[%s]", mystring);
printf("\tout:\t%-14.14s\n", tmpbuf[0]);
```

The comma operator evaluates both arguments and returns its right argument, i.e. `tmpbuf[0]`.

Comment: This is the sane way of writing the code. The original code should only be used if you're attending IOCCC

Comment: @aleroot: There is a comma in that expression

Comment: @hasnobrains: There are no docs short of understanding how C works. Break the expression into smaller and smaller pieces until you either understand what they do or know which question to ask.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'm writing in C for about 10 years already :) And from time to time I'm run into a snippets which, as Alexanre C said, suprises me. So I wonder is there some kind of C cooking book which those guys who wrote that code read :)